# Compare Unicode code point range in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I would like to check if a character is in a certain Unicode range or not, but seems I cannot get the expected answer.

```
char = "？" # the unicode value is 0xff1f
print(hex(ord(char)))
if hex(ord(char)) in range(0xff01, 0xff60):
    print("in range")
else:
    print("not in range")
```

It should print: "in range", but the results show: "not in range". What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hex()` returns a string. To compare integers you should simply use `ord`:

```
if ord(char) in range(0xff01, 0xff60):
```

You could've also written:

```
if 0xff01 <= ord(char) < 0xff60:
```

Answer (score 1):

In general for such problems, you can try inspecting the types of your variables.

Typing `0xff01` without quotes, represents a number.

`list(range(0xff01, 0xff60))` will give you a list of integers `[65281, 65282, .., 65375]`. `range(0xff01, 0xff60) == range(65281, 65376)` evaluates to `True`.

`ord('?')` gives you integer `65311`.

`hex()` takes an integer and converts it to `'0xff01'` (a string).

So, you simply need to use `ord()`, no need to `hex()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Just only use `ord`:

```
if ord(char) in range(0xff01, 0xff60):
    ...
```

`hex` is not needed.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hex#hex):

> Convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”.

Obviously that already describes it, it becomes a string instead of what we want, an integer.

Whereas the `ord` function does what we want, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord):

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, `ord('a')` returns the integer `97` and `ord('€')` (Euro sign) returns `8364`. This is the inverse of `chr()`.